Is it possible to control order of all Admin Menu Items?
There is a task to configure menu items in the admin panel depending on the established rules.


Pages
Stories
Resources
Press Mentions
Team Members
Media
Menus

--Gap--

Theme Settings
Forms
Apperance
Plugins
Users
Tools
Settings
File Manager
ACF

--Gap--

Yoast SEO
Smush Pro

I saw the recommendation about this.
add_action('admin_menu', 'set_pages_menu_position');
function set_pages_menu_position() {
    global $menu;
    $desired_position = 7; // for Pages item

    foreach ($menu as $key => $item) {
        if ($item[2] === 'edit.php?post_type=page') {
            $pages_menu = $menu[$key];
            unset($menu[$key]);
            break;
        }
    }
    $menu = array_slice($menu, 0, $desired_position, true) +
            [$desired_position => $pages_menu] +
            array_slice($menu, $desired_position, null, true);
}

But it seems silly to do this for every item, besides if some new plugin has the same order number, it will cause a conflict and one of the items won't be shown.

May be worth it to try Admin Menu Editor plugin.

Thanks for advice
